# Toggle class on 2 elements

Tags: jquery

I have 2 links doing the same, now I want to add a class off 'active' on both if them when there is one clicked.

I have these two links on different positions in my page:

1:
`<a href="#" title="Software" class="filter" data-filter=".software">Software</a>`

2:
`<a href="#" title="Software" class="filter" data-filter=".software">Software</a>`

And i'm using this code:

```
$('.filter').click(function(){
        var filter = $(this).attr('data-filter');

        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $('a[data-filter="' + filter + '"]').removeClass('active');
        }else{
            $('a[data-filter="' + filter + '"]').addClass('active');
        }

        return false;
});
```

But no matter which link I click, it only changes the second class.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Based on the code you've provided, both links should get/lose the class active.

Comment: I set up a quick fiddle to try it out, and it seems to work fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/dshell/75De9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
$('.filter').click(function(){
  $('a[data-filter="' + filter + '"]').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Was another jQuery plugin who prevented the one from clicked to become active. But the toggleClass method definitly helped, didn't know of it's existence!